# Cannot use BSNL 3g Datacard in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.
I use BSNL 3g datacard for using internet it worked fine with Ubuntu 14.XX but now in the upgraded version I cannot use it is not installing too.
Please help me so that I can use it and I am not able to use it through mobile broadband too.

Thanks

Comment: You mean any wired network is not working??

Comment: @minigeek no wireless 3g datacard or dongle